# Ignore content type on search

Tags: 2010, search, content-type

I have several content type names.

I want to remove one from being indexed so that it doesnt show on my refinement panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the default "All Sites" search scope and add a rule to exclude the specific content type.

First you might need to make the content type a managed property in order to use it in scope rules. Instructions [here](http://velavans.blogspot.com/2010/08/1.html).

Other option is probably to modify the refinement panel itself and hide the specific CT. Example [here](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/01/create-a-content-type-search-refinement-panel-in-sharepoint-2010.html).

Comment: how can I modify the refinement panel?

Comment: Modified answer above to include link to refinement panel modification blog post.