# exclude Document Set content type from showing in search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, document-set, sharepoint-search, result-source

i am trying to create a result source by excluding the document set content type.

I tried by using

```
http://server/site1/published/
NOT ContentType:0x0120D52000FF378E63893F7C449BE61EF8221FE8AB
```

But it is not working.

I am trying to do in sharepoint 2013 and using query builder.

Please help...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i tried by using

```
NOT ContentTypeID:0x0120D520*
```

and it gave me the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem related to this topic [Ignore content type on search](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31661/ignore-content-type-on-search) ?

Or this might help you - specify IsDocument:1 http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/08/26/excluding-folders-from-search-results.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your actual Content Type Id is wrong (it might actually be a child content type of the DocumentSet - most like recovered directly from a Document Library where Document Set has been added). The base Content Type Id is actually 0x0120D520

This being said, you would actually be able to use Content Class (see here http://spreflections.wordpress.com/2010/04/18/leverage-search-crawl-rules-and-content-class-property-to-refine-sharepoint-search-result/ for details) to exclude it.

How you put in place is different either by creating a Search Scope (e.g. an Exclude Rule for the "ContentClass = DocumentSet") or by code in your component (e.g. web part, etc.).

Comment: thank, i tried with 0x0120D520 but no effect,is this id same in 2013 also

Comment: You must use the ContentTypeId property instead if you specify the ID rather than name.